# Greasemonkey script to replace jQuery plugin function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script for Firefox to change the behavior of some pages when they detect a window out of focus. I want the page to continue to function as if it were still in focus, even when I have another tab or window active.

I started out looking at [CAPS Security Policies](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html) which seemed to work for inline Javascript (`window.onfocus`,`window.onblur`), but had no effect on external jQuery script plugin access to focus events.

This is my test page, which uses a jQuery plugin to detect focus. The plugin is inline here, but may also be an external script in some cases.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>jQuery focus test</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $.fn.focuscheck = function() {
        function focusOn () {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Focus event handler fired.</div>';
        };
        function focusOff () {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Blur event handler fired.</div>';
        };

        $(window).bind('focus', focusOn);
        $(window).bind('blur', focusOff);
    };
})(jQuery);

</script>
</head>

<body>    
    <div id="console"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#func').focuscheck();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my Greasemonkey script. I'm trying to adapt jQuery Greasemonkey code from joanpiedra.com. In this case, I tried to completely replace the `focuscheck` jQuery plugin function code from my test page. All the lines are the same as the original except the `function focusOff()` which should display a different result. I don't know if there is a way to do this without replacing the entire function. If that's an option, I might just want to replace the single `focusOff` function or the line with `$(window).bind('blur', focusOff);`.

Right now, the Greasemonkey script doesn't work on my test page. There is no change in the output. Also, I'm not sure if I need to add jQuery to my Greasemonkey script or not, since the page already loads it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          jQuery
// @namespace     http://www.joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey
// @description   Play nicely with jQuery and Greasemonkey
// @author        Joan Piedra
// @homepage      http://www.joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==

// Add jQuery
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); }
    else { $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); }
}
GM_wait();

// All your GM code must be inside this function
function letsJQuery() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.innerHTML = "(function($){\
        \
        $.fn.focuscheck = function(){\
            function focusOn () {\
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Focus event handler fired.</div>';\
            };\
            function focusOff () {\
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>CHANGED event handler.</div>';\
            };\
        \
        $(window).bind('focus', focusOn);\
        $(window).bind('blur', focusOff);\
        };\
    })(jQuery);";

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if there is a way to do this without replacing the entire
>   function

Yes, there is. See code below.

> Also, I'm not sure if I need to add jQuery to my Greasemonkey script
>   or not, since the page already loads it.

You don't have to. See code below.

**The html** (same as yours - i just added "fired from inline JS" to `innerHTML`)

```
<html lang="en">
.
.
function focusOn () {
   document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Focus event handler fired from inline JS.</div>';
};
function focusOff () {
   document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Blur event handler fired from inline JS.</div>';
};
.
.
</html>
```

**The GM script**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE 2
// @namespace      TESTE 2
// @description    TESTE 2
// @include        file:///*
// ==/UserScript==


$ = unsafeWindow.$
$(window).off('blur')

function focusOff () {
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '<div>Blur event handler fired from Greasemonkey.</div>';
};

$(window).on('blur', focusOff);
```

**The result**

[image: result image]

And here, why you should not use `unsafeWindow`: http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow

**EDIT**

About your question in the comments

> Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. I will look into
>   using a safe wrapper instead of unsafeWindow. If you don't mind a
>   follow-up question: [Slide Panel demo](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html) - I tried to adapt similar
>   code to override the click function, with
>   `$('.btn-slide').unbind('click')` then adding a new function, but it
>   doesn't quite work. The event is logged, but the button still
>   activates. `$('.btn-slide').bind('click', function(event) {
>   event.preventDefault(); console.log('button clicked'); });` How can I
>   prevent the slide animation?

The new code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TESTE 3
// @namespace      TESTE 3
// @description    TESTE 3
// @include        http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/*
// ==/UserScript==

$ = unsafeWindow.$

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.btn-slide')
        .unbind('click')
        .bind('click', function(event) {
            alert('my function here')
            console.log('button clicked')
        })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. I will look into using a safe wrapper instead of `unsafeWindow`. If you don't mind a follow-up question: [Slide Panel demo](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html) - I tried to adapt similar code to override the click function, with `$('.btn-slide').unbind('click')` then adding a new function, but it doesn't quite work. The event is logged, but the button still activates. `$('.btn-slide').bind('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); console.log('button clicked'); });` How can I prevent the slide animation?

Comment: @moski No problem. Do you want to open a new question or should i paste the answer here in the comments section?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks again. That's a great help. Now I can make a lot more progress thanks to your assistance. (I only ask after searching and many attempts testing my own solutions.)