# How do I disable body.blur() in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, onblur, document-body

I work on an enterprise web application that runs in IE8. It appears `blur()` is being called on the body causing the IE window to be sent to the background. Unfortunately this code is in a portion of the application that is controlled by the vendor.

Is there any possible way to prevent `blur()` from being called on the body without modifying the code that is actually calling `body.blur()`?

Since this is an enterprise application, solutions outside of changes in the application itself are acceptable; Such as changes to IE8 settings, registry, etc.

Comment: @asawyer - Looking for a quick answer. Not that we won't ask the vendor and submit a bug report to them, but with that process it will be a month before they give us anything useful... if anything at all.

Comment: Sure, but maybe they had a very good reason for they way it is done that way.

Comment: There is no reason at all they would need to call blur() on the body. From what I understand this is only even possible in IE8 and 9. We recently upgraded from IE6, it was at that time the issue became apparent.
/e this vendor portion is a toolbar in our application and it is causing the entire window to be sent to the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to hard code `blur` to a dummy method. If you can get in before it is called, just call `body.blur = function() {};` (assuming `body` is pointing to your DOM body element).

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't thought of this... I will try it out as soon as I get a chance. Thanks Ishmael

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could simply block the event :

```
$('body').blur(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: We do not use jQuery and it would not be feasible to add the framework to our application. thanks though

Comment: Then Ishmael answer is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If using Firefox **is** an option, i have two answers where i propose replacing the function using [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

1. [Using javascript to create a keylistener hotkey for facebook page "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215492/using-javascript-to-create-a-keylistener-hotkey-for-facebook-page-like/10216501#10216501)
2. [Greasemonkey script to replace jQuery plugin function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163168/greasemonkey-script-to-replace-jquery-plugin-function/10174336#10174336)

If you **have to** use IE, you might need to change the page itself.
(I know there is Trixie and [IE7pro](http://www.ie7pro.com) for IE, but never used).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when using javaScript editor:[CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), if I use jQuery blur() method on it, the IE window goes to the background. [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) has it's iframe which has its own body. When you extract that body and use body.blur(), IE browser will go to the background.

Other browsers are not showing that behavior, so it is better to use FF, or Chrome if you are experiencing this.

If you remove body.blur(), probably you would have less problems with IE than you have now, but still you could experience some minor bugs (something is not loosing focus at certain point), but I suppose you could live with it. However if blur() event is enriched with some logic, it could be problem - then find its definition and move logic to some other event that is started with the browser (onload, or ready).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.blur=function(){document.body.focus()}
```